# Performance of Regression Model

Tags: regression

Suppose I ran a multiple regression Model on training data

What are different techniques to assess the performance of that model.

Comment: Have you checked earlier posts on Cross Validated? This kind of questions is both basic and general, so likely it has been answered before.

Answer (score 2):

Before looking at goodness of fit measures, you need to check out your residual plots. The residuals should be centered on zero throughout the range of fitted values, as well as fall symmetrically about zero for the range of fitted values. You should not be able to predict the value of a residual based on the value of another residual. For more information, I recommend the following:

http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-you-need-to-check-your-residual-plots-for-regression-analysis

Now back to your question. Multiple regression will provide you with an equation that minimizes the distance between the fitted line and actual outcomes (i.e. sum of squared residuals, or error terms). How well the model fits depends on how small the differences are between the observed values and the theoretical predicted values. One of the goodness-of-fit measurements is the R-squared (R^2) statistic, or *coefficient of determination*, where:

R^2 = explained variation / total variation.

In other words, R^2 explains the proportion of the variance in your dependent variable that is explained by your predictors.

R^2 ranges from 0 to 100, where:

0 = model explains none of the variability of the response variable
100 = model explains all of the variability of the response variable

In general, the higher the R^2, the better your model fits the data. However, one of the drawbacks of R^2 is that it will necessarily increase when you add predictors to your model, even if that increase is due to chance (as compared to real explanatory power of the added predictor(s)). Another important drawback is that, as you keep increasing predictors, the regression model will begin to model random noise as compared to modeling real data. In this case, even though your R^2 increases, the model becomes useless for making predictions.

To avoid these drawbacks, R^2-adjusted can be used. R^2-adjusted adjusts the R^2 based on the number of predictors in the model. Practically, you can track increases in R^2-adjusted as you add predictors to the model; when the R^2-adjusted stops to increase (or decreases), then you have reached the saturation point and any more predictors will decrease the predictive capacity of your model. Thus, you should use R^2-adjusted to compare models with different number of predictors.